# Understanding event-driven in a Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, event-driven-design, command-query-separation

I've read the code from this Spring MVC application:

https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-rest/tree/master/6/complete/src/main/java/com/yummynoodlebar/core/events

I don't understand the role of those classes from events folder. How can
I catch such a event in another place in application?

Another thing which I don't understand at this application, is why
they doesn't use command-query separation somewhere at service layer. They
used CQS on their rest controllers. I'm not agree with that, instead, they
should use CQS on service-layer to provide a easy way to add validation
or other core operations to their services. [This link describes](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) what I'm 
talking about CQS separation on service layer.

If you have suggestions about how to implement the CQS pattern described in
the link from above, please tell it.